# margin: 0 auto; not centering content

Tags: css, html, web, margin

I'm working on a webpage, and i have the width of my div tag set and am using margin: 0 auto; but my content is still on the left. I'm using OS X 10.7.3, Chrome 19.0.1084.46, and Dreamweaver CS6

here's my CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
    text-align: center;

    display: block;
}
.container {
    float: left;
    height: 2000px;
    width: 964px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.header {
    float: left;
    height: 117px;
    width: 964px;
}
.leftcol {
    float: left;
    height: 1715px;
    width: 534px;
    margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 10.125px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}    
.navbar {
    float: left;
    height: 69px;
    width: 964px;
}
.rightcol {
    float: left;
    height: 1715px;
width: 306px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 20.25px;
}
.video {
    float: left;
    height: 301px;
    width: 534px;
}
.pagebody {
    float: left;
    height: 1749px;
    width: 920px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 21.25px;
    margin-left: 22px;
}
```

And the HTML that uses the CSS:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><img src="Images/Top.png" width="964" height="117" alt="Intelligentlemen Films" /></div>
  <div class="navbar"><img src="Images/RibbonMenu.png" width="964" height="69" alt="Navbar" /></div>
  <div class="pagebody">
    <div class="leftcol">
        <div class="video"><iframe width="534" height="301" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/kMBEuol6aUc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
     </div>
     <div class="rightcol"><img src="Images/intelligentlemen button.jpg" width="300" height="61" alt="Intelligentlemen" /></div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, 
You can't float left and margin auto horizontally. What's the point anyway. You want to have your container centered, not pushed to the left side.
Now that gives you trouble probably, because things don't work out as you'd want them to, because every other element you have there, is floated to the left.

Elements like your header and navbar shouldn't even be floated, they would be perfectly fine even if you didn't float them, they just need to be cleared. You need some reading to do.

Bottom line. When you're floating, you need to clear your floats after you're done with them.

Here is your reading material:
If it's the only thing you do, read at least *The Great Collapse* on CSS Tricks, but I'd suggest reading through it *(and search for more, until it sticks)*

http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/
http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Floats are very important to understand.

p.s. Don't define height on your container, you want that to be flexible, don't you ? I know you're defining the height, again, because you don't understand CSS floats fully. That's why you need to do the reading :)

Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the info and reading! This is my first time doing any real web programming and most of the info out there is less than helpful, but those articles you linked seem useful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack  Overflow then :).

p.s. Now you click the checkmark next to my post, to mark the question as answered ^_^   
That way you establish an "question approval rate" for your self, and I get the benefit of another answered question my profile :)

Answer (score 4):

Because you’ve also applied `float: left;`.

You should also start your source with a doctype declaration, such as `<!doctype html>`, and [ensure your HTML is valid](http://validator.w3.org/), as [well as your CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: I have that but I took it out as it wasn't applicable.